# how can i install pimcore using wamp or xampp on windows 8?

Tags: xampp, wamp, pimcore

I have both `XAMPP` and `WAMP` installed .I am  installing `Pimcore` but there is an error which says `"Couldn't establish connection to MYSQL: Access denied for user 'sadegh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"`. 
I read the installation manual it says i have to create a database manually . how should i create a database? and where should i put it?
can anybody please help?this is killing me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error say, you have to create the database in MySQL yourself. Here is how to do it in XAMPP (very similair for WAMP):

1. Open XAMPP Control Panel and click the "Shell" button
   [image]
2. In the shell window, first connect to the database using the following command:

   `mysql -h localhost -u root`
3. Create a new database with the following command, I named mine "pimcore_sample", also set it to use UTF8:

   `CREATE DATABASE pimcore_sample CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

If all is successful, your output should be something like this:
[image]

Now enter the information into the Pimcore setup, like this:
[image]

Using the root user is not recommended, but works for development. Make sure to create another user for production use (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html).