# Installation of Pimcore on xampp Server?

Tags: xampp, localhost, pimcore

I'm trying to install Pimcore on my local host, I have xampp server.

After searching about it, downloaded the package from website and using shell command prompt i created the database for it.

When I tried to open the pimcore in localhost it is directly re-directing to install like

`localhost/pimcore`

to

`localhost/install`

Here It displaying a message like Object not found.

From this, I'm unable to know how to run it on my localhost!!!

Can any one tell me how to configure it??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i install pimcore using wamp or xampp on windows 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036053/how-can-i-install-pimcore-using-wamp-or-xampp-on-windows-8)

Comment: @user3264805 you're not providing enough information for us to be able to help you out here. Where are you getting stuck? If you set up everything properly (created the database, pimcore sitting in your webservers root) then requesting your domain should redirect you to a setup script

Answer (score 0):

As a rookie I'am struggling with that right now, too. Pimcore somehow does'nt work in subdirectories. If you unpack it in xampp's htdocs directly you can access it by simply using localhost as URL.

The Wiki might help you:
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14551533